# WCF Data Service proxy not in the mood to use the same namespace twice

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, namespaces, wcf-data-services

The first time I created my proxy for a WCF Data Service, the code generator (Visual Studio 2010 SP1) put entity type definitions in:

```
MyClient.DBService.DBModel
```

And the OData feeds coming from the service looked like this:

```
<element p2:type="DBModel.GetWorkstationProfile_Result">
```

This version of the service only exposed *Service Operations*, not entity sets. Happy with the first half of the project, I then started to make some entity sets available, and so I added some access rules for them in the Data Service, like this:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("FooBars", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetWorkstationProfile", ServiceOperationRights.All);
```

I did "Update Service Reference" on the client, but now the proxy puts everything into

```
MyClient.DBService
```

including the Complex Types returned by the Service Operations, and which used to go in `MyClient.DBService.DBModel`.

However, the Data Service is still setting the type of returned elements to `DBModel.GetWorkstationProfile_Result` and so the objects *never get deserialized*. Every call results in an empty list, even though I can check the same query in my browser and see the OData coming from the service just fine.

I can make the proxy code generator go back-n-forth just by enabling or disabling the `SetEntityAccessRule` in the Data Service's `InitializeService` method. Disabled--everything goes in `MyClient.DBService.DBModel`; Enabled--everything goes in `MyClient.DBService`.

Is this a bug in WCF Data Services? How can I convince either the proxy code generator to use its original namespace, or get the Data Service to deliver elements within the new namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a change on the server that results in the new namespace?

You could try deleting the proxy and creating it from scratch.

**Edit**

try:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

Comment: The only change was to add a SetEntityAccessRule to `InitializeService` on the server. I can make it flip between namespaces by doing nothing more than commenting-out that line. Re-generating the proxy from scratch doesn't help, because it generates to whatever "mood" its in at the time (the presence of SetEntityAccessRule)

Comment: Using "*" instead of a specific entity-set name didn't work either. It just puts it into the `MyClient.DBService` mood.